# Is this a valid proof for the given statement?

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be a set of real numbers. Show that a real number $x$ is the supremum
of $A$ if and only if $a ≤ x$ for all $a ∈ A$ and for every positive number $ε$ there is an element $a' ∈ A$ such that $x − ε < a.$

**Attempt:** An equivalent statement: Let $A$ be a set of real numbers. A real number $x$ is not a supremum if and only if $x\lt a$ for some $a\in A$ or $\exists$ $\epsilon > 0$ such that for $a' \in A$ $x-\epsilon \gt a'$

If $\exists a \in A$ such that $a>x$, then $x$ is not an upper bound for $A$ and so $x\neq Sup A$.

if $x \neq supA$, and $\exists \epsilon> 0$ such that $x-\epsilon>a'\\ x>a'+\epsilon\\x+\epsilon > a'+\epsilon \;, \epsilon>0\\x>a'$

Comment: Have you tried drawing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof of the reverse is not valid. You seem to be assuming both (a) $x\neq\sup A$ and (b) there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $x-\epsilon>a'$ for some $a'\in A$. However, you should be assuming just (a) and trying to show that one of the two conclusion statements must be true as a result

This proof is much easier if you try to do it directly, by the way, instead of proving the equivalent statement you provided (although it technically is still correct if you get it, just more difficult).

Comment: thanks. Looking at this a day later I now see how I managed to get myself tangled up.